# What is the content of <packagename>config.cmake files?

Tags: cmake

find_package() in cmake looks for files like

```
 Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3" with any
  of the following names:

    Eigen3Config.cmake
    eigen3-config.cmake
```

I understand this should be created by the package itself, and maybe that comes from processing a Eigen3Config.cmake.in file.
But:

- what would be the actual content of those files?
- is there an example/template with the minimal required info to create that file manually?
- how these files are actually built?

Comment: Far **too broad** for Stack Overflow. "what would be the actual content of those files?" - Just a CMake script, in the same language as you write `CMakeLists.txt`. "is there an example/template with the minimal required info to create that file manually?" - Your could read in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html). "how these files are actually built?" - It is up to the project. In most cases their are created with `configure_file` or even hardcoded.